# How to install a grab bar in a tiled shower

Tags: shower, ceramic-tile, drywall-anchor

I would like to install a grab bar in my tiled shower.  Do I need to find a stud or will wall anchors be enough?

Comment: Studs, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

#### Studs are best

There are anchors that are quite strong. But drywall is sometimes weaker than expected. This is a special concern for a grab bar because the force is not a static weight like a mirror.

If you can mount the bar to 2 studs with long screws then you're set. If not, I would mount a piece of wood to two studs. Paint or stain to match the decor. Mount the grab bar to the wood with screws.

Comment: Wood in a tile shower?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'm pretty sure I've read that anchors won't meet code.  They just can't bear the expected dynamic forces that grab bars are meant to take.

Comment: Oops. I was thinking elsewhere in the bathroom, not in the shower itself. Have to do a little research but probably end up with a metal plate instead of wood.

Comment: open the other side of the wall to install wood.

Comment: @Ecnerwal That is a great idea where it is practical. But depending on what is on the other side of the wall, sometimes that is nearly impossible. (Or rather, so much work would be needed afterwards that it is impractical.)